# pyspark create dataframe from pandas with a column of list of tuples

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a pyspark dataframe from pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType

a_dict = {0: [(0, 9.821), (1, 82.185)]}

a_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_dict.items())
a_pd.columns = ["row_num", "val"]

a_str = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), StructField("prob", DoubleType(), True)])
 my_schema = StructType([ StructField("row_num", LongType(), True),StructField("val", list(a_str), True)]) # error 
                   
a_df = spark.createDataFrame(a_pd, schema=my_schema)
```

error:

```
 AssertionError: dataType [StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(prob,DoubleType,true)] should be an instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'>
```

How to define a valid schema of

```
 list of tuple of (int, DoubleType)
```

so that it can be understood by pyspark?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a list of values, you have to use ArrayType. Below is your code reproduced with examples.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType

a_dict = {0: [(0, 9.821), (1, 82.185)],
          1: [(0, 9.821), (1, 8.10), (3, 2.385)],
          2: [(0, 9.821), (1, 1.4485), (4, 5.15), (5, 6.104)]}


a_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_dict.items())
a_pd.columns = ["row_num", "val"]


print(a_pd.head())



a_str = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), StructField("prob", DoubleType(), True)])
my_schema = StructType([StructField("row_num", LongType(), True), StructField("val", ArrayType(a_str), True)])  # error

a_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(a_pd, schema=my_schema)


print(a_df.show(truncate=False))
print(a_df.printSchema())
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
|row_num|val                                             |
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
|0      |[[0, 9.821], [1, 82.185]]                       |
|1      |[[0, 9.821], [1, 8.1], [3, 2.385]]              |
|2      |[[0, 9.821], [1, 1.4485], [4, 5.15], [5, 6.104]]|
+-------+------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- row_num: long (nullable = true)
 |-- val: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- prob: double (nullable = true)
```